# How can I loop a jsonlite function on a data frame of urls?

Tags: r, json, api, web-scraping

I am trying to run a jsonlite function on a set of API URLs I accumulated. Specifically, I have a dataframe called url_df which has a column called URL with 162800 rows of API URLs. When I write a script and manually insert the each URL at a time it works perfectly fine. This is the script I use to run it manually on one URL at a time:

```
May28 <- 'https://example.example.com/example'. 
May28 <- httr::GET(May28)
May28 <- httr::content(May28, as = 'text')
May28 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(May28)
dplyr::glimpse(May28)
May28 <- as.data.frame(May28)
write.table(May28, file="May28.csv", sep=",")
```

However, because I have over 100K lines of API URLs to go through, I wanted to create a loop function that repeats the above function to each row (each API URL) in the column URL so that I don't have to manually cut and paste each URL to the script 100K+ times. So I saved this information to the dataframe called "url_df" and attempted the following code:

```
j <- 1

for (j in 1:nrow(url_df)){
    url <- url_df$URL[[j]] %>%
  getdata <- GET(url) %>%
  rawdata <- httr::content(getdata, as='text') %>%
  data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(rawdata)
  data_df <- as.data.frame(data)
    print(j)
  j <- j+1
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

For some reason, it will not run. One of the errors I got were:

> Error in jsonlite::fromJSON(rawdata) : object 'rawdata' not found.

One caveat that might be important: each API URL doesn't return just 1 data point value (e.g., 1). Instead, it returns a list of values (e.g., Sunday, 1, Tuesday, 2, etc).

Any ideas on why this might be happening or how I can overcome this?

After solving this first issue, I'd like to then rbind all of the data I collected if possible.

Comment: The way you have used `%>%` is incorrect syntax. I take it is a transposition error when you rewrote the code for SO

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without the `%>%`?
Also, you could try a reproducible example with mock api urls like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `for` loop fails is because you have some invalid or problematic URLs.

See if something like this would solve your problem:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Function to download - it takes two inputs: (1) url and (2) save file name
dl_my_url <- function(url_address, file_name_to_save){

  x <- httr::GET(url_address)
  y <- httr::content(x, as = 'text')
  z  <- jsonlite::fromJSON(z)

  print(dplyr::glimpse(z))

  output <- as.data.frame(z)

  write.table(output, file = file_name_to_save, sep=",")

}

# make the function safe in case some url fails
safe_dl_my_url <- safely(dl_my_url)

# Run the function (make sure you create a save name for each url)
url_result <- map2(urldf$address, urldf$file_name_to_save, ~safe_dl_my_url(.x, .y))

# To get your results
map(url_result, "result") %>% bind_rows() # or bind_cols which ever works for you

# Check what is failing
map(url_result, "error")
```